# Update a table using values from another table

Tags: mysql-5.6, update, concat

I have two tables with structure

```
Table1
------   
No | Name | IDNo | HouseNoBlock

Table2
------ 
IDNo | HouseNo | Block
```

I am trying to update the `HouseNoBlock` Column of first table with value joined by `HouseNo/Block` while comparing the `IDNo` . I was able to get the values using the query

```
SELECT CONCAT(table2.HouseNo,'/',table2.Block) 
FROM   table2 ,table1 
WHERE  table1.IDNo = table2.IDNo
```

but when I try to `UPDATE` table1 I am getting a `Syntax error ERROR 1064 (42000)` .

```
UPDATE table1 
SET    HouseNoBlock = CONCAT (table2.HouseNo,'/',table2.Block) 
FROM   table2 ,table1 
WHERE  table1.IDNo = table2.IDNo
```

Can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not supplied any data, I've prepared next example:

```
create table tbl1 (No int, Name varchar(200), IDNo int, HouseNoBlock varchar(200));

create table tbl2 (IDNo int, HouseNo varchar(100), Block varchar(100));

insert into tbl1 values 
(1, 'Name1', 1, null), 
(2, 'Name2', 2, null), 
(3, 'Name3', 1, null);

insert into tbl2 values 
(1, 'House1', 'Block1'), 
(2, 'House2', 'Block2');
```

Use next sentence:

```
UPDATE tbl1  --< first the table that will be updated
JOIN   tbl2
ON     tbl1.IDNo = tbl2.IDNo
SET    HouseNoBlock = CONCAT(tbl2.HouseNo,'/',tbl2.Block);
```

This is final result:

```
No | Name  | IDNo | HouseNoBlock 
-: | :---- | ---: | :------------
 1 | Name1 |    1 | House1/Block1
 2 | Name2 |    2 | House2/Block2
 3 | Name3 |    1 | House1/Block1
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a9bda648ad7ddcf09520476c1eb03926)*

Have a look at [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) about UPDATE syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in **table_references** that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

Comment: Can you please clarify on which table to use first on a comparison `WHERE`  clause .

Comment: The table that will be updated.

Comment: My tbl1 is really large with some 18 billion rows and i need this join to be restricted using a `WHERE` condition on tbl1  at the end of query , but still it is traversing whole rows , will adding the `WHERE` condition to join with an `AND` will work  .